# elasticsearch exclude aggregation bucket by subaggregation doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch

I think it'll be easier to explain with a query. Consider my query:

```
GET _search
{
   "aggs": {
      "group_by_app": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "application"
         }
      },
      "aggs": {
         "installs": {
            "filter": {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "action": "install"
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            }
         },
         "launches": {
             "filter": {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "action": "launch"
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This returns me with below result:

```
"aggregations": {
      "apps": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "app1",
               "doc_count": 2313,
               "launches": {
                  "doc_count": 0
               },
               "installs": {
                  "doc_count": 48
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "app2",
               "doc_count": 5,
               "launches": {
                  "doc_count": 0
               },
               "installs": {
                  "doc_count": 0
               }
            },
         ]
     }
}
```

Now if you notice, installs and launches are both 0 for app2. I do not want the bucket for key = "app2" to show up in the result if both sub-aggregates launches and installs are 0.

I saw [min_doc_count](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count) and was wondering if it was possible to do something similar for my case?

[EDIT]: The other thing I thought that I could try was that, instead of doing aggregation "group_by_app" for every possible "action", If I could aggregate it over ONLY "action" = "install" OR "action" = "launch". So basically what I mean is that the bucket aggregation is only over "action" = "launch" OR "install", and sub-aggregation are basically the same in the query. I can do a min_doc_count over the bucket aggregation to not show sub-aggregation results. However aggregation only allows term/terms or filter and not both. If somebody can suggest an alternative way to achieve that, even that would be a great help!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `min_doc_count`, that helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized it wasn't that difficult. Instead of trying to filter in the aggregation, I can just use "query" to limit the documents I am aggregating over. So instead of aggregating over all the documents for all "application" with every "action", Only aggregate over documents for all "aplication" with only two "action", namely "action" = "install" OR "action" = "launch", and then do a min_doc_count = 1 over the bucket aggregation will not show "application" bucket if both "install" and "launch" sub-aggregation are 0.

Here's the complete query:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "bool": {
                   "must": [
                      {
                          "fquery": {
                             "query": {
                                "match": {
                                   "action": "install OR launch"
                                }
                             },
                             "_cache": true
                          }
                      }
                   ]
               }
           }
        }
    }, 
   "aggs": {
      "group_by_app": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "application"
         }
      },
      "aggs": {
         "installs": {
            "filter": {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "action": "install"
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            }
         },
         "launches": {
             "filter": {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "action": "launch"
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this works for the particular use case, but wont work if I wont to show a bucket depending on a different min_doc_count on subaggregations.